# Load and Unload iAd view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

How can I load/unload an iAd when a button is tapped? In other words I want to be able to load  a iAd banner when a button is tapped and unload it when another button is tapped.

With the following code I'm able to load and display the banner when the loadBanner button is tapped, the issue starts when I tap the unloadBanner button, it actually unloads the banner but if I click the loadBanner button again it doesn't re-load the banner, which is essentially what I want.

How can i re-load the banner after being removed?

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
- (IBAction)loadBanner:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)unloadBanner:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m file

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    BOOL _bannerIsVisible;
    ADBannerView *_adBanner;
}

- (IBAction)loadBanner:(id)sender {
    // iADBanner
    _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 66)];
    _adBanner.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)unloadBanner:(id)sender {
    [_adBanner removeFromSuperview];
    _adBanner.delegate = nil;
}

// ===================================
// ********* BANNER  ****************
// ===================================
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        if (_adBanner.superview == nil)
        {
            [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try this:  either in the loadBanner or unloadBanner method do a _adBanner = nil;

Comment: Also, it looks like you did not reset your _bannerIsVisible bool after you unload.

Comment: Adding `_bannerIsVisible = NO;` to unloadBanner did the trick. Thanks a lot. Do I really need `_adBanner.delegate = nil;` in unloadBanner? Deleting it doesn't do any difference visibly and works fine without it.